# Always getting a NullPointerException on adding a spinner to my fragment

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments, android-spinner

I'm trying to create a contact list with a spinner where you can choose different roles for contacts.

I'm always getting a NullPointerException on adding the spinner to the layout of my contact list (list_item.xml) and I just can't find my mistake(s).

kontakte_fragment - XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        tools:context="match_parent"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:background="#ffffff">


            <ListView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="657dp"
                android:id="@+id/listViewKontakte" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

The Layout for my List (list_item.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="#ffffff">




        <com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.CircularImageView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:src="@drawable/screen1"
        app:siBorderWidth="2dp"
        app:siBorderColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/kontaktListePic"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/titelKontaktListe"
        android:id="@+id/textview1kontakteTitel"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/kontaktListePic"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/kontaktListePic"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/kontaktListePic"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/unterTitelKontaktListe"
        android:id="@+id/untertitelKontaktListe"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview1kontakteTitel"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textview1kontakteTitel"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textview1kontakteTitel" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinnerKontakte"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/untertitelKontaktListe"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="250dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

KontakteFragment - ActivityClass

```
public class KontakteFragment extends Fragment {

    private ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

    Spinner spinner;
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;


    public static KontakteFragment newInstance() {
        KontakteFragment fragment = new KontakteFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    public KontakteFragment(){

    }




    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.kontakte_fragment, container, false);

        ListView lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listViewKontakte);
        generateListContent();
        lv.setAdapter(new MyListAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.list_item, data));

        spinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerKontakte);
        adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.array.profile_kontakte, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        return rootView;
    }

    private void generateListContent() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 55; i++){
            data.add("This is row number" + i);
        }
    }

    private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

        private int layout;

        public MyListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);
            layout = resource;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder mainViewHolder = null;
            if(convertView == null){
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
                convertView = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);
                ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.thumbnail = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.kontaktListePic);
                viewHolder.titel = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview1kontakteTitel);
                viewHolder.unterTitel = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.untertitelKontaktListe);
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

            }

            else{
                mainViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                mainViewHolder.titel.setText(getItem(position));
                mainViewHolder.unterTitel.setText(getItem(position));
            }

            return convertView;
        }
    }

    public class ViewHolder {

        ImageView thumbnail;
        TextView titel;
        TextView unterTitel;

    }

} // This is the end of our KontakteFragment Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `Spinner` in the Fragment's layout, but it's in the LitsView's elements layout. 
You can get a proper reference to your Spinner inside your Adapter's `getView` method, like so :

```
Spinner yourSpinner = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerKontakte);
```

Comment: So i should insert " Spinner yourSpinner = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerKontakte); " into my getView method?

Comment: Exactly ! The spinner is not in the fragment's layout file, so looking for it there returns null, causing the exception you encountered.

Comment: Another thing : if your spinner always shows the same available values, you could store those as an array in a resource file and refer to it in the xml, thus removing completely the need to set the adapter manually in the code, like so : android:entries="@array/your_array"

Comment: First of all thank you for your help, but there is still the NullPointerException :/

Comment: Are you sure it's the same one ?? Your spinner is in the layout file you inflate in getView, so it should not be null... You of course need to set your spinner adapter inside getView as well...

Answer (score 0):

Where did you added Spinner in fragment? you are doing this in wrong manner

```
public class KontakteFragment extends Fragment {

private ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;


public static KontakteFragment newInstance() {
    KontakteFragment fragment = new KontakteFragment();
    return fragment;
}

public KontakteFragment(){

}




public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.kontakte_fragment, container, false);

    ListView lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listViewKontakte);
    generateListContent();
    lv.setAdapter(new MyListAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.list_item, data));


    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.array.profile_kontakte, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    return rootView;
}

private void generateListContent() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 55; i++){
        data.add("This is row number" + i);
    }
}

private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    private int layout;

    public MyListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        layout = resource;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder mainViewHolder = null;
        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);
            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.thumbnail = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.kontaktListePic);
            viewHolder.titel = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview1kontakteTitel);
            viewHolder.unterTitel = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.untertitelKontaktListe);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            viewHolder.spinner = (Spinner)convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerKontakte);
        }

        else{
            mainViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            mainViewHolder.titel.setText(getItem(position));
            mainViewHolder.unterTitel.setText(getItem(position));
          // here you have to set data to spinner 
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}

public class ViewHolder {

    ImageView thumbnail;
    TextView titel;
    TextView unterTitel;
    Spinner spinner
}

  }
```